# Ordinary Infinity and Dedekind Infinity

Tags: set-theory

Does anyone know a good proof for the claim that one can add a finite number of elements to a set A, which is an ordinary infinity (take their union), and A will still be equipollent to this new set. (I'm looking for a proof in the ZF system, so you cannot say that an ordinary infinity is a Dedekind infinity.) Does such a proof even exist? (I have a feeling it does not).

One says that set A is Dedekind-infinite if some proper subset B of A is equinumerous to A.

One says that set A is Ordinary Infinite if it cannot be put in bijection with a finite ordinal, otherwise it is Ordinary Finite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The claim is not true in ZF alone. It is consistent with ZF that there are *infinite* (i.e. not finite) sets which are *Dedekind finite* (i.e. not equinumerous with any proper subset). For such sets, adding even one element changes the cardinality.

---

Two further comments:

- The amount of choice needed here is very little; *countable choice*, for instance, is more than enough.
- Choice can fail in even more drastic ways. It is consistent with ZF that there are infinite sets which cannot be partitioned into two disjoint infinite sets - such sets are called **amorphous**. Clearly every amorphous set is Dedekind-finite, but the converse is not true: being amorphous is strictly stronger than being infinite and Dedekind-finite.

Comment: Can you tell me where I can read about this? Do you have a proof for this claim? The claim makes sense, but just because infinite is not Dedekind infinite (in ZF) does not mean that one element can change the cardinality. So how do you know this? Thanks.

Comment: @YitzchakShmalo Yes, it does: suppose $X$ and $X\sqcup\{x\}$ have the same cardinality. Then there's a bijection $f: X\sqcup\{x\}\rightarrow X$. But now the set $\{f(y): y\in X\}$ is a proper subset of $X$ which is in bijection with $X$, so $X$ is not Dedekind-finite.

Comment: As for a Dedekind-finite, infinite set in ZF: Cohen's original model of ZF+$\neg$AC has a set of reals which is Dedekind-finite but infinite. For an amorphous set, you have to do a bit more work, but not much; I forget who first did that. (It's a good exercise to show that you can't every have an infinite amorphous set of reals.) In general, you should look at Jech's book "The axiom of choice."

Comment: But you don't want to show that  f(y) is a  bijection with X. You want to show that {f(y):y∈X}{f(y):y∈X}  is a bijection with x, no? How do you show that?

Comment: In fact, I don't believe that it can be placed into a bijection.

Comment: @YitzchakShmalo You want to show that $X$ is in bijection with a proper subset of itself. That proper subset, here, is the set $Y=\{f(y): y\in X\}$ - this is a *proper* subset of $X$ since $f(x)$ is in $X$ but not $Y$. And the bijection between $Y$ and $X$ is given by $f^{-1}$: $f^{-1}(Y)=X$. Do you see why?

Comment: Here's another way to prove it: suppose $X\sqcup\{x\}$ is in bijection with $X$ via $f$. Look at $\{x, f(x), f(f(x)), . . .\}$. This set is in bijection with $\omega$, which is Dedekind-infinite. Any set which has a Dedekind-infinite subset is Dedekind-infinite.

Comment: I like the second proof, thanks. (Although I assume that you don't want to keep x in the set.)